# Unknown value in Incompatible shapes error from Keras/TF

Tags: keras

I'm getting started with Keras and I think I'm missing something regarding how layers interact together.

I have this shape of data :

```
x shape : (696, 5, 6)
y shape : (696, 5, 2)
```

And a really simple model that I'm just trying to make work to keep exploring

```
inputShape = (xtrain.shape[1], xtrain.shape[2])    
batchSize = xtrain.shape[0] / 6
outputDim = ytrain.shape[2]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(500, activation='relu', input_shape=inputShape, batch_size=batchSize))
model.add(Dense(500, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(outputDim, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse')
```

And I can't figure out where is the `32` coming from in this error

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [116,5] vs. [32,5]
```

Comment: `Dense`layer doesn't takes `batch_size` argument.

Comment: Your code ran fine for me (after putting an `int()` wrapper on `batch_size` division). Makes me wonder if it's a version problem. What TF version are you using? Are you crossing imports from TF Keras and vanilla Keras? (e.g. `import keras.backend as K, from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential`)

Comment: @TheLoneDeranger you mean that I should import keras through TF?

Comment: No, you can use either vanilla keras OR keras through tensorflow, whichever you prefer is fine, but crossing them---importing some functions from vanilla and others from tensorflow---typically produces errors, especially with strange and unexpected tracebacks. I was just trying to rule it out as a potential cause. It sounds like the code worked for me only because I never tried to fit it (only took it as far as compile, as above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have it, Vincent. Let me explain you what is going on:

- When passing `batch_size=batchSize` to the first `Dense` layer, the model is expecting all the inputs to have batch size `batchSize`.
- However, when you fit your model via:

  ```
  model.fit(xtrain, ytrain)
  ```

  the error is raised, because the default value for the argument `batch_size` of [`model.fit`](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit) is 32, which is what `model.fit` uses to create the batches from `xtrain` and `ytrain`.

There are two possible solutions to fix this issue:

1. You can set the argument `batch_size` of `model.fit` to `batchSize`.
2. A more flexible solution is to remove `batch_size` (or set `batch_size=None`) of the first `Dense` layer. This allows to have dynamic batch sizes - the network works for all batch sizes (e.g. you can set `batch_size` of `model.fit` or `model.predict` to an arbitrary value).

Comment: That totally brings me to the next step! It is the answer for this problem :)  It brings me to another issue for which I'll investigate but just in case, do you think this next problem is linked with the original question? `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError:  Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(160, 6), b.shape=(6, 500), m=160, n=500, k=6`

Comment: Great :) No, it is most likely not linked to the original question. In fact, I never found this error. I am happy to take a look at it in a new question, provided that you provide all the necessary code to reproduce it.